# prove that G has a circle with a length of 4.

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to prove the following:

Let G be a graph with n vertices. For each two vertices x, y which are not neighbors, occurs:

d(x) +d(y) >= n

I need to prove that G has a circle with a length of 4.

I'm thinking about induction. If we have a graph with n vertices that has a  circle with a length of 4, adding another vertex won't harm it. And the base of the induction is easy to find. Is this proof legal?

Comment: Isn't $G=K_3$ a counterexample? Maybe you left out some assumption?

Comment: Let's say $G$ is not a complete graph, so we can choose two vertices $x,y$ which are not neighbors. Can you use the identity $$|N(x)\cup N(y)|+|N(x)\cap N(y)|=|N(x)|+N(y)$$ along with other things you know to prove that $|N(x)\cap N(y)|\ge2?$

Comment: Where does your attempted "proof" use the assumption that $d(x)+d(y)\ge n?$ I guess your argument "proves" that every graph contains a $C_4,$ right? Take a graph $C_4$ as the base of the induction. If you have a graph with $n$ vertices that contains a $C_4$, then adding another vertex won't harm it. Well, actually, all this proves is that a graph which contains a $C_4,$ contains a $C_4.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for induction. Also, as stated it is not entirely true. How could there be a cycle of length $4$ if $n<4$?

Assuming $n\geq 4$, take $x, y$ not neighbours. Look at the set $U$ of neighbours of $x$ and the set $V$ of neighbours of $y$. How many vertices could $U$ and $V$ at most cover (i.e. what's the maximum possible size of $U\cup V$)? Considering that adding their sizes makes at least $n$, how much overlap must they at least have? Use that to make a cycle of length $4$.

If you can't find non-neighbouring $x, y$, then your graph is complete. Because $n\geq 4$, there must be a cycle of length $4$.